# Could not find module in path: 'react/jsx-runtime' relative to

Tags: reactjs

I try to make this exercise : [How to Build a Todo List with React Hooks](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-todo-list-with-react-hooks-ebaa4e3db3b/)
But there is an error inside the [codeSandBox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-forked-lx9ksz). What wrong ?

Comment: Where is the error? because it seems that it is working just fine.

Comment: In fact I changed the dependencies versions. then reloaded the page. That resolve the problem. Hereunder the capture of dependencies. That worked for you because the link I sent you have kept the new dependencies versions. I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I changed the dependencies versions. then reloaded the page. That resolve the problem. Hereunder the capture of dependencies. That worked for you because the link I sent you have kept the new dependencies versions. I don't know how.

[image]